# Get particular tag block from html string in iOS?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I'm working on a project in which I want to get a particular HTML block for use. How can I do that? For ex:

```
<div class="row pos-relative">
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="standard-story-details-main-img" id="image-video-section">
<img src="https://new-img.title.com/upload/2017/11/11/exam_1990063_835x547-m.jpg" title="Entrance Exam" alt="à¤à¥à¤à¤¦à¥à¤° à¤¸à¤°à¤à¤¾à¤° à¤¨à¥ à¤¦à¥ à¤®à¤à¤à¥à¤°à¥, à¤ªà¥à¤°à¤¤à¤¿à¤¯à¥à¤à¥ à¤ªà¤°à¥à¤à¥à¤·à¤¾à¤à¤ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤¹à¥à¤à¥ à¤à¤ à¤à¥à¤¸à¥à¤à¤¿à¤à¤ à¤à¤à¥à¤à¤¸à¥" /> </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to get particular div having "standard-story-details-main-img" class or "image-video-section" id so I try like:

```
NSString *imgStr = [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"image-video-section\")[0].innerHTML;"];
```

or using class also like:

```
NSString *DetailStr = [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('standard-story-details-main-img')[0].innerHTML;"];
```

But in both case it will return @"" to me.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/tid-kijyun/Kanna

Comment: When are you calling this? The webview must be loaded at this point, so `webViewDidFinishLoad` would be a good place.
Also try your javascript i.e. in Safari console to see if there is any error message.

Comment: @Wasserfloh Yes I'm calling this after webViewDidFinishLoad but still return @"".

Comment: can you open your html file in safari?
Then go to Developer -> Javascript Console and type in your lines of javascript there to see the return value or an error message.
Looking at the first line: `getElementById` will return a single object, so `[0]` is not correct, should be `document.getElementById(\"image-video-section\").innerHTML;`

Try to track down the issue by executing i.e.
first `document.getElementsByClassName('standard-story-details-main-img');`
then `document.getElementsByClassName('standard-story-details-main-img')[0]`
and look at the console output